# CATextLayer cannot align to center horizontally with UILabel text in swift

Tags: ios, swift, catextlayer

When i use CATextLayer in swift 5, i align it to center by using Horizontal alignment modes follow [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catextlayer/horizontal_alignment_modes)
but it cannot align to center. Here is some of my code

```
myLabel.textAlignment = .center

textLayer.frame = myLabel.bounds;
textLayer.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center
```

But when i run on ipad pro, i set position x to 500 and it moved to center

```
textLayer.position = CGPoint(500,20)
```

But it's not exact and i don't know the reason why it is. So how can i align the CATextLayer exactly to the center as the center Label text?

Comment: what is textLayer ?

Comment: textLayer is an object of CATextLayer.
var textLayer:CATextLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.frame = myLabel.bounds;
textLayer.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center
...
cell.myLabel!.layer.addSubLayer(textLayer)

Comment: When are you setting the `.frame` and / or `.position`? If auto-layout has not finished its work, the frame and bounds are probably not yet set.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag. i will check again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is textLayer in your code but if you want use CATextLayerAlignmentMode you can set it to your label

```
  myLabel.textAlignment = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center
```

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'CATextLayerAlignmentMode' to type 'NSTextAlignment'
myLabel.textAlignment uses NSTextAlignment, so myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center. And... textLayer.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center